# MySql запрос функционирует не верно

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Буду краток: нужно вывести количество строк в таблице message. `$x = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM message")` всегда выводит 1, но при этом `$x = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM message")` функционирует как надо. Однако второй вариант, как все знают, далеко не самый лучший. Объяснять почему не буду. Собственно, дамы и господа, вопрос: почему первый вариант выдает не то значение?

Comment: Как вывод осуществляется? Думаешь тут телепаты сидят?

Comment: `echo mysqli_num_rows($x);`

Comment: Ну естественно тебе возвращается один ряд, и в нем значение COUNT(*)

Comment: Как предлагаете выводить тогда ?

Comment: Делать fetch и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Если первый вариант, то:

```
$x = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM message");
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($x);
$count = $result["count"];
```